# Is there a limit on the number of parameters an MVC route can handle?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, routes

I am writing an MVC Application using MVC Areas. Currently we are using the following route for our display area:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Display_default",
        "Display/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{id2}/{id3}/{*id4}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional , id2 = UrlParameter.Optional, id3 = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

And this works. However we discovered the need for a controller action with 6 parameters:

```
public ActionResult _MyMethod(string id, string id2, string id3, string id4, string id5, string id6)
```

we discovered we can add this we the current setup, however any parameter in the url after the forth id is just concatenated into the 4th id parameter.

We tried to extend the route to accept the number of parameters that we needed like so:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Display_default",
        "Display/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{id2}/{id3}/{id4}/{id5}/{*id6}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional , id2 = UrlParameter.Optional, id3 = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

However, using this route the page no longer loads.

Does MVC Routing have some sort of CAP as to the amount of parameters it can map to? We also discovered that if we shrink the number of mapped parameters to id, id2, and id3 it will work however again with all overflow concatenated into id3.

Does anyone have any information around this?

Comment: You can have as many as you want (up to the point where you would exceed the query string limit and throw an exception). But only the last parameter can be marked as `UrlParameter.Optional`

Comment: Ok, so in my case above why would it not allow the 6 parameters I need?

Comment: Have you removed all the `UrlParameter.Optional`. And why have you marked the 6th with `{*id6}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET MCV has no limit on the number of parameters.

In your case

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
{
   context.MapRoute(
      "Display_default",
      "Display/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{id2}/{id3}/{id4}/{id5}/{*id6}",
       new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional , id2 = UrlParameter.Optional, id3 = UrlParameter.Optional }
   );
}
```

Variable *id* is optional however *id4* is mandatory. You have to add optional parameters into the end.

Like

```
 routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Default",
      url: "{controller}/{action}/{id5}/{id6}/{id}/{id2}/{id3}/{*id4}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, id2 = UrlParameter.Optional, id3 = UrlParameter.Optional, id4 = UrlParameter.Optional, id5 = UrlParameter.Optional , id6 = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Or make all of parameters optional

```
routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Default",
      url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{id2}/{id3}/{id4}/{id5}/{*id6}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, id2 = UrlParameter.Optional, id3 = UrlParameter.Optional, id4 = UrlParameter.Optional, id5 = UrlParameter.Optional }
 );
```

Comment: Only the last parameter can be marked as `UrlParameter.Optional`

Comment: @Stephen Muecke Why you think so? These code works fine for me, Do you have any documentation? I have investigated `routes.MapRoute` call stack, I have finished in `ParsedRoute.Matched` method http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/fx/src/xsp/System/Web/Routing/ParsedRoute@cs/1305376/ParsedRoute@cs Line 518 there are no evidence that only one parameter could be marked as `UrlParameter.Optional`.

Comment: Because if you do not provide all of them, the routing engine has no way of knowing which is which and therefore uses a query string, not route values (making the route definition pointless)

Comment: If you don't provide all of them, the routing engine will take them according to url order. In these case if you pass `Home/Index/1/2`, you would receive `id = 1, id2 = 2,` and other parameters would be null. It works in same way as if with one parameter and (in same way pointless for me).

Comment: And what if the 2 value was for `id3` (e.g. `@Html.ActionLink('xxx', 'Index', 'Home', new { id = 1, id3 = 2 }, null)` - you need to spend some time studying how routing works

Comment: I got your view It is obvious. I mean with optional parameter you could avoid to have 3 routes. 1)`url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}`
2)`url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{id2}",
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id, id2 = UrlParameter.Optional, }`
3)`url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{id2}/{id3}",
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id, id2, id3 = UrlParameter.Optional, }`